# How to aggregate method time in jprofiler call tree

Tags: java, jprofiler

I am trying to root cause a performance issue in java. I got the sampling profile using jprofiler. I can see many different URIs which have at the root the same method call (xss2csv)

Eg

> User1File1
>
> > something
> >
> > > xss2csv
>
> User2File2
>
> > something
> >
> > > xss2csv

I want to find out the total % time taken by xss2csv method. The individual calls show 140s (all states), but hotspots view shows 0s for this method.
Please advise.

Let me know if any more info is reqd.

Answer (score 0):

Hot spots do not show total time but inherent time. What constitutes the inherent time depends on your filter settings.

To see the total time for a method look at the call graph. You can right-click a method in the hot spots view or the call tree view and select "Show call graph" from the context menu.